# How do I replace a module with a dev version through the UI?

Tags: drush

I copy the reference to the dev release for a module and paste it into the "Install module" form, but Drupal complains that the module is already installed. Is there a good way of doing this through the UI or drush or do I just have to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: This seems to me like "pretty similar to the question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3897 ... no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that I can run `drush dl <module_name>-8.x-1.x-dev` and confirm that I was to override the old module.